# SSRS - Semi-Blank page when Tablix exceeds page1 space

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

My Title to this question is probably a little confusing, but let me try explain what happens.

Our company report template requires a header and a footer. The footer is displayed on every page, but the header should only be displayed on page 1.

To achieve this, we removed the header content from the report header and placed it at the top of the report above the Tablix. This produced the desired results, but we now have the issue where we get semi-blank pages.

Some background:
 - The header of page 1 takes up about 5cm of the page.
 - There are no overlapping controls on the page.
 - **InteractiveSize property:** 21cm, 29.7cm
 - **Margins property:** 1cm, 1cm, 0cm, 0.5cm
 - **PageSize property:** 21cm, 29.7cm

Now lets say on page 1, there is **X** amount of space for the tablix data (Because of the header), but from page 2 to the end there is **Y** amount of space for tablix data.

The problem we get is when the total amount of data that should be rendered is between **X** and **Y**. The report then renders the 1st page with the header, but apart from that and the footer, the page is blank. Then on page 2, the Tablix will display the data.

If the amount of data is less than **X** or more than **Y**, then we have no problems; the report renders as expected.

Can anyone maybe point me in the right direction please?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the tablix's [KeepTogether](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reportingservices.reportrendering.dataregion.keeptogether%28SQL.100%29.aspx) property is set to `True` so that when there isn't enough room on the first page but there is on the second page for the entire tablix, it then renders on the second page.

Set it `False`

Comment: Chris, you are a STAR! Thanks a lot.
I made a silly, rookie mistake :)